# NSObjectController confusion binding to a class property. Help!

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I'm teaching myself cocoa and enjoying the experience most of the time. I have been struggling all day with a simple problem that google has let me down on. I have read the [Cocoa Bindings Program Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000167) and think I grok it but still can't solve my issue.

I have a very simple class called MTSong that has various properties. I have used @synthesize to create getter/setters and can use KVC to change properties. i.e in my app controller the following works:

```
mySong = [[MTSong alloc]init];
[mySong setValue:@"2" forKey:@"version"];
```

In case I am doing something noddy in my class code MTSong.h is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MTSong : NSObject {
    NSNumber    *version;
    NSString    *name;
}
@property(readwrite, assign) NSNumber *version;
@property(readwrite, assign) NSString *name;
@end
```

and MTSong.m is:

```
#import "MTSong.h"

@implementation MTSong

- (id)init
{
    [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@synthesize version;
@synthesize name;
@end
```

In Interface Builder I have a label (NSTextField) that I want to update whenever I use KVC to change the version of the song. I do the following:

1. Drag NSObjectController object into the doc window and in the Inspector->Attributes I set:

   - Mode: Class
   - Class Name: MTSong
   - Add a key called version and another called name
2. Go to Inspector->Bindings->Controller Content

   - Bind To: File's Owner (Not sure this is right...)
   - Model Key Path: version
3. Select the cell of the label and go to Inspector

   - Bind to: Object Controller
   - Controller Key: mySong
   - Model Key Path: version

I have attempted changing the Model Key Path in step 2 to "mySong" which makes more sense but the compiler complains. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Scott

---

Update Post Comments

I wasn't exposing mySong property so have changed my AppController.h to be:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class MTSong;

@interface AppController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSButton *start;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *tf;
    MTSong *mySong;
}
-(IBAction)convertFile:(id)sender;
@end
```

I suspect File's owner was wrong as I am not using a document based application and I need to bind to the AppController, so step 2 is now:

2. Go to Inspector->Bindings->Controller Content

   - Bind To: App Controller
   - Model Key Path: mySong

I needed to change 3. to

3. Select the cell of the label and go to Inspector

   - Bind to: Object Controller
   - Controller Key: selection
   - Model Key Path: version

All compiles and is playing nice!

Comment: As `NSNumber` and `NSString` both conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, you should use the `copy` attribute for those properties rather than `assign`. This prevents a problem where your property is set to a mutable object (e.g. an `NSMutableString`). This can then be changed by some other code, and your object does not then contain the value you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind the controller's content to the mySong key path as you suggested. What you are perhaps not doing is exposing mySong as a property or instance method in the File's Owner (typically your application delegate).

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin. See the edited post above for my corrections to solve the problem post your input.